# How to send a csv file as an email attachment

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to send a csv file by email and I am able to use the messageUI but when I add the attachment code, the app crashes. The file is in documents directory. The error and the code:

Error:

```
Assertion failure in -[MFMailComposeInternalViewController 
addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:], 
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/MessageUI/MessageUI-
3445.0.13/Mail/MFMailComposeInternalViewController.m:742
2018-02-20 18:25:54.649811-0700 oFiOSstoryboard[1385:174595] *** 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-
[MFMailComposeInternalViewController 
addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:] attachment must not be nil.
```

```
- (IBAction)sendmail:(id)sender {
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        MFMailComposeViewController *mail = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mail.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mail setSubject:@"Sample Subject"];
        [mail setMessageBody:@"Here is some main text in the email!" isHTML:NO];
        [mail setToRecipients:@[@"testingEmail@example.com"]];
        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"jorg.csv"];
        [mail addAttachmentData:myData
                                mimeType:@"text/csv"
                                fileName:@"jorg"];
        [self presentViewController:mail animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"This device cannot send email");
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Point out the exact line causing the error. 2. Include the complete and exact error in your question. 3. You make no attempt to load the file from the Documents folder.

Comment: "jorg.csv" is not a correct path to a file for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is with:

```
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"jorg.csv"];
```

You state the file is in the Documents folder but this code makes no reference to the Documents folder at all.

You need something like this to get the data:

```
NSString *docFolder = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *path = [docFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"jorg.csv"];
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```